# asp.net session dissappers

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a strange problem:
I have a site which has an administration system.

In the system there is a way to edit my inputs. To make this easier, I can search for their ids to find them.

The problem is when the page posts back the session variable I hold the "logged in" value in, becomes nothing.. and i get kicked out. Why is that happening? Session variables should hold at least 20 minutes if anything else is stated?

EDIT: It works for a coworker, but not for me.. Also, it only does it on certain inputs.

EDIT2: Turns out i get an exception. but it doesnt say what, only says "property evaluation failed". i get it on this code row:

```
Response.Redirect("./admin.aspx?search=" + u.FirstOrDefault.ProductID.ToString, False)
```

And sience it goes through this statement, its not because it is an objectreference not set to an instance of an object

```
If u.Any Then
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Can you post some code to make it easier to investigate the problem ?

Comment: I could post code, but what code is relevant? sience i don't remove/abadon the session anywhere on the page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you experience an exception your session might be restarted.
Create a global.asax and set breakpoints to the Application_Error, Session_End and Session_Start events to track down the issue

**Edit based on your update**:
Make sure that u.Count == 1, because FirstOrDefault will throw an exception, if the count is > 1.

Have a look at this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/ which should cover your original problem
http://forums.asp.net/t/1296202.aspx/1

Comment: That could be so, ill check into it

Comment: @Jimmy: But breakpoints for Session_Start were hit, right? If that is not the case, you should check whether you override your "logged in" value with a String.Empty or something like this

Comment: Yes they were, changed a few things and it seems to work now, Thanks! Next time till debug more closely. Strange that it worked with my co-worker though..

Answer (score 0):

If you have Web Garden enabled (multiple worker processes for an application pool) this can explain such behavior - been there.

Either have one worker process for the pool, or switch to [Database driven Session](http://idunno.org/articles/277.aspx).

Comment: I dont think so, if its not standard.

Comment: @Jimmy Just check the IIS configuration, it should be under the Application Pool properties.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you have cookies enabled?**  If not, this would explain this behavior.  Especially as you state it works for the co-worker, you can deduce it's a client-side issue.